# Scala Fold operation using a Tuple

Tags: scala

```
val g = List(1,2,3)

val k = g.fold((0,0))((a:Tuple2[Int,Int],b:Int)=>(a._1+b,a._2+1))
```

But i get the below error =

```
found   : ((Int, Int), Int) => (Int, Int)
 required: (Any, Any) => Any
              g.fold((0,0))((a:Tuple2[Int,Int],b:Int)=>(a._1+b,a._2+1))
```

Can someone please explain ,why its expecting a "Any" Type.

But below worked:

```
g.map((_,1))

g.map((_,1)).fold((0,0))((a,b)=> (a._1+b._1,a._2+b._2))
res211: (Int, Int) = (6,3)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It looks like you mean to use `foldLeft`:

```
val k = g.foldLeft((0,0))((a:Tuple2[Int,Int],b:Int)=>(a._1+b,a._2+1))
```

`fold` has the signature

```
def fold[A1 >: A](z: A1)(op: (A1, A1) ⇒ A1): A1
```

so it requires the element type to match the accumulator type, while your example has different types for both.

Answer (score 0):

To answer specifically this part:

> Can someone please explain ,why its expecting a "Any" Type.

Lee's answer gives the signature: `fold[A1 >: A](z: A1)(op: (A1, A1) ⇒ A1): A1`. In your case the compiler knows `A` is `Int`, and you pass `(0,0)`, which has type `(Int, Int)`, as `z`. So `A1` has to be a supertype of both `Int` and `(Int, Int)`. `Any` is their least upper bound.